# Passing constant reference... does it work like most important const?

Tags: c++, function, reference, constants

It's a known special case that constant references are not lost in return values if they're assigned as constant references:

```
int MyFunction()
{
    int x = 5;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    const int& y = MyFunction();
    std::cout << "This is valid: " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now if I have two functions like the following:

```
int MyFunction()
{
    int x = 5;
    return x;
}
void MyOtherFunction(const int& val)
{
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
     MyOtherFunction(MyFunction());   
}
```

Does this work **according to the standard**? What are the limitations of  passing const references?

Comment: Yes it works, you can bind temporaries to constant references. The limitations are that you can't modify `val`.

Comment: Yes. You could also bind to a non-const rvalue reference if you wanted to.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Sure you can. You can bind it to an rvalue ref or you can safely `const_cast` away the `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine too: the standard mandates that an anonymous temporary (`MyFunction()`)can bind to a const reference.

(It can't bind to a non-const reference; some compilers are lapse on that).

Comment: I'm curious; what would a non-anonymous temporary look like?

Comment: I'm just asking. Sigh.

Comment: So I remove the `const` from the MyOtherFunction, then it won't work. Right?

Comment: The behaviour of your program would be undefined. As a quantum physicist I'm sure you can hypothecate on what that could be. And congratulations on finding the new particle by the way.

Comment: That's wrong. [The program would not compile, actually](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd55f1b7e9cd9149).

Comment: Oh I wish, try on Visual Studio 5.0.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Even if I were to do that (why the frak would I?!?!?!) _lifetime extension still applies_ so once you've used the extension to allow the initial binding, you have no undefined behaviour. So it's still a wrong statement.

Comment: Absolutely. I was a very young cat in the days of VS5.0. But I did have a fine morning once changing refs to const refs, trying to get some code working with gcc. Terrible memories. I blamed the French quants.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

> `[C++14: 12.2/5]:` *[..]* A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the *full-expression* containing the call. *[..]*

Comment: Phew. You switched to "Yes". No need to spend this afternoon refactoring ;-) Plus one, now I have time.

Answer (score -1):

it is valid. . 
Reference is just an alias to your variable and it represents the address location where the variable stored.

const reference means you cannot modify your const arguement inside your function.

In ur case,
MyOtherFunction(MyFunction());

here MyFunctions returns an int which stores as anonymous variable whose life time is upto that expression.

Comment: -1: Missing the point that we're talking about lifetime extension through reference binding. Also somewhat misrepresenting what references _are_.

Comment: Donno where I've mistaken can you elaborate. . ?? thnx fr ur vote .!

Comment: thnq very much. . kudos to u